# Is it possible to list all the threads currently running in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'd like to list as much information about all the threads currently running in .NET1.0 as I can. I don't have the luxury of adding threads to an internal list of my own when they get created; I just want to dump out a list of those that are currently in the system. Does any one know a way of doing this? I've been looking at the System.Threading... namespace and right now nothing is opening up as I hoped it would.

Comment: Process.Threads, but it is only available in 1.1 and forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about 1.0 but in 1.1 you can use:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

If a Process's Modules collection contains mscoree.dll/mscorjit.dll, it is a .Net thread. The version of the .Net framework the application is running, can also be found by the information provided by the modules.

Comment: From MSDN it would appear it is only available in .Net 2.0 and up

Comment: It is supported from 1.0 onwards as this msdn doc shows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx I don't have VS2003 to check it though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to break into the process, the .Net debugger will provide you with a list of all currently executing threads.  It might also help you to know that provided you have a thread run through a code path you control, you can access it's thread object (`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`) and give it a name, which you can then print out into any debugging messages.  (Assuming .Net 1.0 has this...)

I know it's a lateral answer but it might help.